# How to run CloudFront without Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

Currently I am running on an S3 bucket + CloudFront a static website. I have registered outside my domain but currently using it with route 53.

For each domain on Route 53 I have to pay 0,50$ per month (For each new zone, and I want to add a lot of domains).

I would like to use the dns server of my domain provider (Currently inwx.com).

It this possible and how? (For www. and non www. pages)

Comment: It's $0.50 per hosted zone, not per domain.

Comment: Yes, but I need for each domain a new hosted zone. Is that right?

Comment: For each domain, but not subdomain. Using your current DNS provider has the drawback of not have alias records. That can be problematic because you can't CNAME the top domain. Using another dns provider is fine otherwise.

Comment: I have different domains. Like exampleone.com exampletwo.com etc. 
>> That can be problematic because you can't CNAME the top domain => This is actually my problem. How can I solve this with another dns provider? can you give me an example? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is possible to use a Cloudfront distribution using a registrar other than AWS without a Route53 public hosted zone. You don't need Cloudflare to do it.

You can create an Alias record with the subdomain and target in your registrar's control panel. The target would be something like `dabcxyz.cloudfront.net.`

I tried this with success using Namecheap but I'm sure other registrars with similar DNS features can provide the same service.

This way you will not incur the monthly $0.50 charge.

I'm not sure about the the CNAME but I'm able to host subdomains and www's without a public hosted zone.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this situation too and my choice was Cloudflare. It has a free option and it supports CNAME flattening on the apex (so you can effectively CNAME to the CloudFront domain). If you go down this road, you'll need:

- add Cloudflare nameservers as NS records (to make Cloudflare the authoritative nameserver for the domain)
- use ACM to get a certificate (add the CNAME validation record to Cloudflare)
- add the Alternate Domain Name to the CloudFront distribution
- and finally add the CNAME record pointing to the distribution (make sure you use the DNS only option)

I wrote [an article](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-a-custom-domain-on-cloudfront-with-cloudflare-managed-dns/) on how I configured it.

Comment: But this solution is also not working for the root domain. Is that right?

Comment: It works. Cloudflare supports CNAME records on the root.

Comment: @TamásSallai So what do you input as origin domain in cloudfront configuration. I followed your article as well, but there is no mention of Origin domain in your article.

Comment: @sanjayojha Try the S3 bucket

Comment: @Parag, I have WP site hosted on Linode. I want to use it.

Comment: @sanjayojha, yeah, it should be the S3 bucket. The idea here is that Cloudflare only adds the HTTPS, and the content is coming from CloudFront. So make sure that the site works with just CloudFront (without the custom domain), then add Cloudflare and check if it works with the custom domain